# Is all this *really* the 'safe' area and how far down UINavigationController puts UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, layout, uinavigationcontroller

*** UPDATE: THIS IS WHAT IT LOOKS LIKE WHEN YOU HAVE A
NAVIGATION CONTROLLER IN A NAVIGATION CONTROLLER ***

I have a tab bar as a navigation controller.  My views present like this (the navigation controller decides its placement).

Does that look right? That seems pretty far down on the screen (in the simulator), notch notwithstanding.

Without doing a custom controller for the Navigation Bar, is there some reasonable way to reclaim some of that space above the navigation bar by sliding it up?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default, top safeArea contains status bar offset and navigationBar offset.

You can have only the status bar offset should you hide the navigation bar.

So, the code may help.

`navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true`

Comment: Thanks, however I definitely want the navigation bar, just higher up on the screen

Comment: Which margin? How? Can you add an example to your answer? (note the bar is being provided by the navigation controller)

Comment: Also keep in mind the UINavigationBar is not in the same hierarchy as the UIView of the UIController it is appearing over.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the project I was a big confused about the navigation controller stack and wrapped a tab bar controller, and later made one of the tab bar controller children controllers a navigation controller as well, so apparently iOS was stacking the navigation controllers and making the first one invisible. Removing the 2nd navigation controller let everything move up.